# Why is DatagramPacket object get stuck when using one of it's methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp, packet

I am using a server and a client to share information via UDP packets.
The client assembles a packet and sends it to the server.
The server receives the packet , **and issues a thread to handle it**.

In the threads code I try to use the packet but I get stuck for every method I use: getAddress()  , getData() , etc.
When I try to use the packet's methods in the Server's code - it doesn't get stuck. Only in the Threads'.
**I don't understand why I get stuck when using the packet in the thread's code**

Here is the code and **it compiles**:
**The Client**

```
public class ExchangeClientProgram
{
    public final double ERROR = 0;
    private DatagramPacket packet;
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private InetAddress hostAddress;
    private int port;
    private byte [] buf;

    public ExchangeClientProgram(String hostIp , int port) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException
    {
        this.port = port;
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostIp);

    }

    public boolean sendRequestPacket(ExchangeRequest exchangeRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            buf = ExchangeServerProgram.convertObjectToByteArr(exchangeRequest);
            if(null != buf)
            {
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, hostAddress , port);
                socket.send(packet);
                return true;
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, this exchange cannot be trasnmitted to server");

        } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        return false;
    }


}
```

**The Server**

```
public class ExchangeServerProgram extends Thread
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 4444;
    public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private DatagramPacket packet;
    private boolean listening = false;// default initial value
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    public ExchangeServerProgram() throws SocketException
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT);
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer , buffer.length);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        listening = true;
        while(listening)
        {
            try
            {
                socket.receive(packet);
                packet.getAddress(); // this line BEFORE the thread starts works fine.
                new ExchangeClientRequestHandlerThread(packet ).start(); // inside this thread the trouble starts 
                                                                        // when using the SAME line from above

            } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }

    }

    public static byte [] convertObjectToByteArr(Object obj)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte [] buffer = null;
        ObjectOutput out = null;
        try {
          out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
          out.writeObject(obj);
          out.flush();
          buffer = bos.toByteArray();
        } 
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace(); } 
        finally {
            try
            {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

**The Thread** Handling The Packet, here is where I get stuck

```
public class ExchangeClientRequestHandlerThread extends Thread
{
    private DatagramPacket packet;
    public ExchangeClientRequestHandlerThread(DatagramPacket packet)
    {
        this.packet = packet;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if(null == packet)
            return;
        packet.getAddress(); //... get stuck here

        System.out.println("doesn't get to this code line");
    }

}
```

**ExchangeRequest**

```
public class ExchangeRequest implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1355753051547829379L;
    private String coinFrom;
    private String coinTo;
    private double amount;
    private int requestId;

    public ExchangeRequest(String coinFrom, String coinTo, double amount , int requestId)
    {
        this.coinFrom = coinFrom;
        this.coinTo = coinTo;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }
    //getters & setters

}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ExchangeServerProgram server = new ExchangeServerProgram();
            server.start(); // starts the server

            String inputIpAddress = "localhost";
            ExchangeClientProgram clientProgram = new ExchangeClientProgram(inputIpAddress, ExchangeServerProgram.DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT);
            ExchangeRequest request = new ExchangeRequest("usd", "euro", 4, 1111); // 1111 is just an ID number for the message
            clientProgram.sendRequestPacket(request);

            while(true)
            {
                // this while loop is just for the example  
                // here I am waiting for received packet  
                // via "socket.receive();"
            }
        } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Saying "it compiles" is like saying you wrote an essay and all the alphabets are correct. I.e. it doesn't really tell much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading is your problem. You have one thread calling `receive(packet)`, and when you receive it you pass it to another thread for processing, making the first thread call `receive(packet)` again.

The problem is that `receive` synchronizes on `packet` and methods in `DatagramPacket` are synchronized, so while the first thread is blocked on `receive(packet)` you can't call any of the `DatagramPacket` methods without it blocking the thread.

Possible solutions include processing the packet in the original thread or creating a new `DatagramPacket` for each `receive()`.

Comment: Aww shucks, twain't nothing.